# Laravel export downloadable CSV file

Tags: laravel, csv, export

I am trying to write an endpoint which exports the data from the users table i currently have into a CSV file which is downloaded upon clicking of a button. I have setup the controller, routes, export file, and added in the button within the view but everytime i go to click the button it just directs me to the `admin/user/export` then gives me a 404 but shouldnt it just stay on the same URL then just add the file to my downloads file?

This is the package i am using for Laravel

https://github.com/maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

**web route**

```
  Route::get('users/export', 'Admin\UserController@export')->name('users.export');
```

**UserExport**

```
class UsersExport implements FromCollection
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return User::all();
    }
}
```

**Controller Function**

```
public function export()
{
    return Excel::download(new UsersExport, 'users.csv');
}
```

**Summarise problem:**

Everytime i click the button on the view page it directs to `admin/users/export` then gives me a 404 when i want it to just download the CSV file for the users.

Some help to see where i am wrong would be helpful!

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it should download the file without redirecting, make sure you are actually accessing the correct route (maybe try a `dd(123);` in your `export()` action). Currently it looks like a route conflict to me, do you have a route similar to this: `Route::get('users/{user}');`?

Comment: Your a star! yeah it was a route problem i had it set to `users` instead of `user` is there a way you can modify the columns

Comment: You can keep it as `users`, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that two of your routes conflict with each other.

Given the following two routes:

```
Route::get('users/{user}', 'Admin\UserController@show')->name('users.show');

Route::get('users/export', 'Admin\UserController@export')->name('users.export');
```

Currently Laravel assumes that when you are trying to access `users/export` you actually want to access `users/{user}` with `export` as the route parameter `{user}`.

Making sure that `users/export` is registered **before** `users/{user}` should solve your issue:

```
Route::get('users/export', 'Admin\UserController@export')->name('users.export');

Route::get('users/{user}', 'Admin\UserController@show')->name('users.show');
```

Comment: That makes sense thanks for the teaching! do you have much experience with this package can you easily enough add columm headings etc? ill have a look through the documentation but i wasnt sure if it was best to custom write this exporting or use this package to make life easier(was suggested in alot of threads) and the controller less cluttered?

Comment: Yes you can use the `WithHeadings` concern and add your headings, you can read more about it [here](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/mapping.html#adding-a-heading-row).

Comment: Thanks for that Remul! have a great day/evening!